# Prevent container from shutting down at console exit

Tags: virtualization, libvirt, lxc

As the manual clearly states, an LXC container automatically destroys (shuts down) itself when you exit the console. However, we're using these machines as servers (sshd, sometimes apache, ...) and I want the machines to be running until I shut them down explicitly. Is that possible using LXC / libvirt? With OpenVZ, this seemed to be the default behaviour.

Comment: What prevents you from exiting the console via "Ctrl-a" "q" ?

Comment: Thanks for the hint. However, it just doesn't feel natural. When I'm on a physical machine, or any virtual machine of any other technology I know so far, `exit` either just exits the console or else displays a login prompt again. Why is lxc so different?